# How to get the clicked element in selenium when we don't know what are we clicking

Tags: selenium

I am clicking with the help of following lione oc code->

```
actions.moveToElement(objDriver.findElement(By.id("id_popcode")),coordinates.getX(),coordinates1.getY()-1).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Basically i double click at a position(x,y) in our application. Individually we cannot click that particular element bcoz it has to be clicked at particular (x,y) itself. So i want to get the properties of that clicked element(which i click using actions command which i mentioned above) liked `id, classname`. Can some one help me with this...kinda stuck here..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

try execute`.elementFromPoint()` with `JavascriptExecutor` to get element by coordinates

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement theElement = (WebElement)js.executeScript("return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1])", coordinates.getX(), coordinates1.getY()-1);
System.out.println(theElement.getAttribute("tagName"));
System.out.println(theElement.getAttribute("class"));
```

---

old:

you are using negative value in `getY()-1` which mean coordinates above the element, it maybe the `parent` or `preceding-sibling` of element try to select it using xpath

```
WebElement popcodeBefore = objDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='id_popcode']/parent::*"));
// Or
// WebElement popcodeBefore = objDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='id_popcode']/preceding-sibling::*"));

System.out.println(popcodeBefore.getAttribute("class"));
actions.moveToElement(popcodeBefore).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Comment: Hii, I'm just clearing my question. With the help of my command i actually click far away from the element(with id - id_popcode). Think that element with id(id_popcode) is at top right  and with that command i am click at middle of the screen.  The middle of the screen has no elements until i click using that actions command.

Comment: I understand your question it just alternative way. Edited the answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any specific text at that particular coordinates make use of it. I too had the same issue like this where I need to double click on a cell which had text 0.00%. I have done hovering action first using the text and then performed the double-click

Ignore the syntax issues since I am working on the protractor these days

```
browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(driver.findElement(by.xpath("//*[text()='00')]").build().perform();
```

and then perform the click

Still, you have issues, check if you have any attribute like ng-click which can be helpful to get the coordinates for that particular location. please always share the HTML code so that It may help us to check more deeply